# Textures not rendering in EEVEE but renders in cycles w/blender 2.8 even with image nodes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, eevee-render-engine

[image: eevee]

When I go to render in cycles the textures properly render but in EEVEE most of them don't show up, is this a limitation of eevee or am I doing something wrong? Thanks